# remove numbers from a list with words

Tags: list, digits

I suck at this so Ill try to be as clear as possible

I have a list which I made from a text file.
example it looks like:

### ['john,10','bob,20','ray,30']

tats how its prints out.
I know I can access each unit like (list[0])

### john,10

But is there a way to remove either the numbers or letters only from say list[0]

### john

probably weird question

Answer (score 0):

In this situation,you can try to use the approach like below:

    `In [62]: guys=['john,10','bob,20','ray,30']
    In [66]: guys_new=[]
    ...: for i in guys:
    ...:     guys_new.append(i.split(',')[0])
    ...: print guys_new
    ...:
['john', 'bob', 'ray']`

Comment: awesome, that is very close to what I need. I will play with it for a bit.

Comment: Is it possible to make the reverse true as well, taking just the numbers out instead to put into a separate list? Changing the [0] value to [1] isn't working

Comment: @ultima Of course you can,use the trick,say,`[-1]`,to see what will happen.If those I said in the former can help you a little bit,a vote for me is welcome .^_^.

Comment: i did vote, but I have less than 15 rep so, it doesn't count lmao

Comment: @ultima So do I,it's okay,LoL...Btw,I learn a new word of Imao from you,it's very funny after I searched in natural language translation engine named dict.youdao.com which is very popular in China.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what language you are using. If you are using an language like C++, you can use the ctype header

```
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string list[] = {"john,10", "bob,20", "ray,30"};
    string temp = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //3 = num elements
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < list[i].length(); j++)
        {
            if(isalpha(list[i].at[j])
            {
                temp = temp + list[i][j];
            }
        }
        list[i] = temp;
        temp = "";        
    }

}
```

- Step 1: get the element from the list
- Step 2: Check each character at    a time to see if it is a
  alphabetic value. Sometimes there is a built    in function.
  Sometimes you have to create a bunch of if-then    statements or a
  switch-case statement.
- Step 3: Append all of the    alphabetic values to a temporary
  variable
- Step 4: Reassign that    element in the list to the value of temp

Comment: I am using python atm, I apologize for not including that